# Did a man buy a house to show a middle finger sculpture to his ex-wife?

Tags: divorce

[image: The picture I’m talking about]

> Saviez-vous que ?
>
> En 2013, un homme a acheté une maison à côté de celle de son ex-femme juste pour qu’elle puisse voir tous les jours la statue géante du doigt d’honneur qu’il y a installé.

I know this is fake, and I’m sure I’ve already seen this “story” a few times already with different dates, but I can’t find the source, just this image with different watermarks.

Roughly translated from French:

> Did you know?
>
> In 2013, a man bought a house next to his ex-wife’s just so that she
>   would see a middle-finger sculpture pointed at her house every day.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, people do things like that. Here's an excerpt from an [article about this specific case](http://www.myfoxdetroit.com/story/23985382/man-buys-the-house-next-to-ex-wife-erects-giant-middle-finger-statue) on a local news site.

> Alan Markovitz recently moved into the home where the statue was
>   erected, which happens to be next to the home where his ex-wife now
>   lives with her new lover, whom she reportedly had an affair with while
>   being married to Markovitz.
>
> Markovitz tells Fox 2's Randy Wimbley his plan was to get even with
>   the ex-wife's new lover, and never meant for the matter be made
>   public. However, it soon grabbed local attention when the ex-wife's
>   daughter posted a picture of the statue on twitter.
>
> The installation of the statue also included a spotlight to keep the
>   message illuminated at all hours of the day.